# incorrect memcopy() use when transferring structs

Tags: c

I have two structs

```
struct word_count_struct 
{
    char *word;
    int count;
};
```

and

```
struct bag_struct 
{
    struct word_count_struct *bag;
    int bag_size;
    int total_words;
};
```

I am trying to put a copy of a word_count_struct into *bag by using memcopy. I'm not too sure as to why, but im getting segmentation faults whenever my program tries to memcopy the word_count_struct into *bag. I think it might have something to do with the arguements for memcopy I am using:

```
struct bag_struct *bow;
struct word_count_struct *WCS;
    bow = realloc(bow,sizeof(struct word_count_struct) * (bow->bag_size + 1));
    memcpy(&(bow->bag) + bow->bag_size ,WCS, sizeof(struct word_count_struct));
```

I didn't show it here, but bow and WCS both get initialized with proper values (except bow.bag).

Comment: Check your destination. Why do you add `bow->bag_size` there?

Comment: Could you show initialization, too? It is common for a correctly written `realloc` to break because of something you did in a previous call.

Comment: Probably you've forgotten to allocate a piece of memory where the copy should be stored and set bag to point to it

Comment: In calling `realloc(bow,sizeof(struct word_count_struct) * (bow->bag_size + 1));`, what is the value of `bow` as used in `bow->bag_size`?  Hint: `bow` is not initialized.

Comment: Apart from `bow->bag` rather than `&(bow->bag)` what does `bow->bag` even point to? Similarly for `WCS` - it is an unitialised pointer - unless you have elided the code, in which case that should be indicated or the code included.

Comment: There is no need to use memcpy. Just use a struct assignment, which is much more likely to allow the compiler to tell you when you do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is very likely incorrect: `&(bow->bag) + bow->bag_size`

The address of `bow->bag` is inside `bag_struct` structure. Adding `bow->bag_size` to it gives you a pointer that is past the end of `bag_struct`, causing undefined behavior. What you want is either this `&(bow->bag[bow->bag_size])` or this `bow->bag+bow->bag_size`:

```
memcpy(bow->bag+bow->bag_size, WCS, sizeof(*bag));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally, totally confused.

You want just *one* bag_struct. The bag_struct can contain any number of word_count_struct. bow should be just a struct bag_struct, properly initialised with bag_size = 0, total_words = 0, bag = NULL.

The thing to realloc is bow.bag, to a size of (bag_size + 1) * sizeof (word_count_struct). And you store a word_count_struct by assigning bow.bag [bow.bag_size] = *WCS and increasing bow.bag_size.